# Command-line options to force googletest to run in single thread

Tags: multithreading, googletest

I have a suite of unit tests that is managed by googletest. These tests are run in multiple threads by default, even when I use `--gtest_filter=foo.test` so that it only runs a single test. This is causing ambiguity about the cause of a bug I'm trying to hammer out.

How can multithreaded testing be turned off in googletest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no commandline switch for single/multi-threading. `libgtest` is built either
single-threading or multi-threading.

To make it single-threading, build gtest with `./configure --with-pthreads=no`, then link your unit test app without `-pthread`

If you only want single threading sometimes, then make a no-pthreads build of `libgtest`,
call it something else, and link it when you want.

Answer (score 6):

If you are building googletest with cmake, you can use the cmake option `gtest_disable_pthreads` to control support for threading. For example:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. -Dgtest_disable_pthreads=ON
```

The resulting output should *not* show:

```
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
```

Then you can run `make` as usual.

Answer (score 5):

Another option short of rebuilding with multi-threading disabled is to simply create a test fixture for tests that cannot run concurrently. Then in the SetUp() and TearDown() methods, lock and unlock a mutex respectivey.

Be sure to use a mutex that exists outside of the test fixture, as the fixture is created and torn down for every test.

```
std::mutex g_singleThread;

class SingleThreadedTests
{
protected:
   virtual void SetUp() override
   {
      g_singleThread.lock();
   }

   virtual void TearDown() override
   {
      g_singleThread.unlock();
   }
};

TEST_F(SingleThreadedTests, MyTest)
{
   // ...
}
```